# Добавить maven в IntelliJ IDEA в обычный java проект

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Как мне это (именно версии **7.0.13**).

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cit.unimi.dsi%7Cfastutil%7C7.0.13%7Cjar

добавить в IntelliJ IDEA в обычный java проект ?
Не вручную, cкачивая jar...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно выгрузить библиотеку из Maven.
Для этого:
1. Войти в структуру проекта;
[image]
2. В разделе "Библиотеки" выбрать "Из Maven";
[image]
3. Ввести путь к библиотеке (можно искать как по groupId, так и по artifactId).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 16):

1. Нажать на папку с проектом правой кнопкой
2. Выбрать "Добавить поддержку фреймворка"
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Выбрать из списка Maven

Answer (score 14):

Поздний ответ, наверное, но для истории:

Можно в корень обычного проекта в IDEA добавить pom.xml (хоть из другого проекта), подправить ему group, artifact, зависимости. Потом в контекстном меню для этого файла выбрать "Add as Maven Project". Проект станет теперь maven, дальше уже настраиваем его как обычный maven-проект.

**Update** простейший XML файл имеет вид

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>........</groupId>
    <artifactId>.....</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Comment: Если вы еще добавите шаблон `pom.xml`, ответу цены не будет.

Answer (score -3):

Создать maven проект и подключить зависимость, будет скачиваться автоматически

Comment: А если не Maven проект ?

Comment: @Andreyua загруженную библиотеку взять с майвен проекта скопировать в нужный и подключить лол)

Comment: Так и я умею ... лол

Comment: Других вариантов нет