# Ошибка: "Cannot resolve symbol support"

Tags: java, maven, selenium, импорт, testng

Всё было в порядке. Выгрузил проект из битбакета и при импорте:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.expectedconditions
```

Он мне дает ошибку. Что ему не нравится?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы загрузили необходимые библиотеки ?

Comment: Непонятно, все было в порядке где и когда ? Возможно, нет библиотек в локальном репозитории, или среда незакешировала наличие библиотек (если они реально есть в локальном репозитории). Попробуйте, сначала скомпилировать (mvn compile), если проект корректен, то необходимые библиотеки подкачаются в локальный репозиторий. Дальше будет понятно что делать по результату компиляции.

Comment: Там же серым по черному видно, что он этого импорта не видит по его `file path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решилась следующим образом: pom.xml - add to maven project
Он всё сам подкачал, чего не хватало. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В проекте используется сторонняя зависимость, и сборщик зависимостей Maven, его следует добавить
[Добавить maven в IntelliJ IDEA в обычный java проект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562432/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-maven-%D0%B2-intellij-idea-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

затем подтянуть необходимую зависимость, собрать проект и получить профит