# Добавление сборщика проектов (JAVA)

Tags: java

Можно ли в уже скажем написанный проект добавить сборщик проектов, если да то как? (желательно в Intellij IDEA)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562432/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-maven-%D0%B2-intellij-idea-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В корень обычного проекта в IDEA добавить pom.xml, подправить ему group, artifact, зависимости. Потом в контекстном меню для этого файла выбрать "Add as Maven Project". Проект станет теперь maven, дальше уже настраиваем его как обычный maven-проект.

Простейший XML файл имеет вид

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>........</groupId>
    <artifactId>.....</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)