# Как добавить maven в существующий Java-проект в IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Добавил pom.xml в корень проекта:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.infy</groupId>
  <artifactId>user-identity-rest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Перезапустил IDEA и сбоку появилась плашка Maven.

Однако, почему-то в External Libraries ничего нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал clean и install делать, но ничего...

И в самом проекте не подсасывается тип из либы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я упустил?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавить maven в IntelliJ IDEA в обычный java проект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562432/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-maven-%d0%b2-intellij-idea-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-java-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82)

Comment: в контекстном меню pom.xml выбрать "Add as Maven Project"

Answer (score -1):

Скопируйте из другого существующего проекта папку .mvn и пересоберите проект[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Нет такой папки в проектах